# Node JS routing functionlity with calling rest

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest

I'm fairly new to node js and I need to develop some kind of **reverse proxy** in node JS which is getting some URL with path and I need to route the call to rest APi according to the URL (identify the URL by some regex),there is some example or some module which I can use which is open source.
Example and direction how to do it right will be very helpful! :)

Answer (score 1):

For example

```
url = "http://example.com/profile"
```

`req.get('host')` will give the hostname like  **http://example.com**.

in  `req.url` you can get url **/profile**

1. https://www.npmjs.com/package/request
2. https://nodejs.org/api/http.html

use expressjs for routing http://expressjs.com/
 For example

```
app.get('/profile', function (req, res) {
  res.send('GET request to homepage');//or render profile page
});
```

Comment: Thanks,Can you please provide more meaningful example?I need to use it for routing and I dont understand how to route with your example?

Comment: use expressjs for routing http://expressjs.com/
 For example
app.get('/profile', function (req, res) {
  res.send('GET request to homepage');//or render profile page
});

Comment: Thanks I voted up, can you please provide addtional info how you got some diffrent request and route it to diffrent rest service call,thanks in advance!

Comment: @JhonDree Please take a look API doc of expressJS. http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.get
You will definitely get mush  more information and its very easy.